# async await not working with Node.js gdrive API v3

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

hoping you can help me figure this one out. Pretty stumped as to why this is giving me issues.

Following the quickstart guide, I'm able to get the files printed to the console. Cool, I see the second argument in `files.list` is a callback that's passing in the `res/error`

Node: v8.3.0
npm: v5.3.0

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const keys = require('./credentials.json');

const app = express();

const drive = google.drive('v3');

const scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"
];

// Create an oAuth2 client to authorize the API call
const client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  keys.web.client_id,
  keys.web.client_secret,
  keys.web.redirect_uris[0]
);

// Generate the url that will be used for authorization
this.authorizeUrl = client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: scopes
});

// Open an http server to accept the oauth callback. In this
// simple example, the only request to our webserver is to
// /oauth2callback?code=<code>
app.get('/oauth2callback', (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code;
  client.getToken(code, (err, tokens) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    client.credentials = tokens;
    // set auth as a global default
    google.options({
      auth: client
    });

    listFiles()
    res.send('Authentication successful! Please return to the console.');
    server.close();
  });
});
// This prints out 10 files, all good.
function listFiles() {

  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    q: "name = 'US'"
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('The API returned an error.');
      throw err;
    }
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (const file of files) {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Specifically, the `listFiles` function is not working when I try to use async/await.

Here's what that looks like:

```
async function listFiles() {
  const res = await drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    q: "name = 'US'"
  });
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}
```

It's logging `undefined`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try wrapping it in a `try/catch` and logging the `err`

Comment: you used `drive.files.list` in the first example and `service.files.list` in the await example.

Comment: Ok, so there was something weird with the `googleapis` npm install. I reinstalled it and I'm getting my files logged out now. Yay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do is `npm uninstall googleapis` and then `npm install googleapis --save` and that did the trick. Super weird, but glad that I'm able to clean up my code with async/await =)

Comment: This works and it's super weird. Does first run without async/await change something in the node_modules itself?

Comment: Oh my, thank you for this. I just blindly followed the instructions `npm install googleapis@27 --save` from Google's own [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs). Your answer helped me realize that I simply needed a newer version of googleapis.